# Cron Job runs multiple times in Laravel - Production Server

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a project in Laravel 8 as the backend deployed on EC2 with ubuntu. I have scheduled few functions as cron jobs at specific time. But, the same cron job seems to run multiple times. So i put a test function as follows.

```
     $schedule->call(function () {
        Log::info('function testing');
     })->dailyAt('8:00')->timezone('Asia/Qatar');
```

The above log prints around 39 times. After my research i added withoutOverlapping()

```
     $schedule->call(function () {
        Log::info('function testing');
     })->dailyAt('8:00')
       ->timezone('Asia/Qatar')
       ->name('unique_event_name')
       ->withoutOverlapping();
```

The above one prints around 9 times.

I have a development server with the same code and similiar `env`. There it works fine. It is running only one time.

```
* * * * * cd backend_path && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The above command i runs on `crontab -e`.

I'm attaching my `Kernel.php` file below

```
     <?php
    namespace App\Console;
    
    use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Mail;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
    
    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
    {
        /**
         * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $commands = [
            'App\Console\Commands\DatabaseBackUp'
    
        ];
    
        /**
         * Define the application's command schedule.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
         * @return void
         */
        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            $schedule->call(function () {
               Log::info('function calling');
            })->dailyAt('8:00')
               ->timezone('Asia/Qatar')
               ->name('unique_event_name')
               ->withoutOverlapping();
    
            // scheduler for Data Base backup twice daily 3 AM and 15 PM
            $schedule->command('database:backup')->twiceDaily(3, 15);
            
        }
       /**
       * Register the commands for the application.
       *
       * @return void
       */
       protected function commands()
       {
          $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

          require base_path('routes/console.php');
       }
   }
```

I'm unable to figure out the issue with my production server, Any help will be appreciated !!

I have changed my root folder to new repository in the same instance and removed the old folder. Will it effect any cron job functionality?

Comment: Post your `App\Console\Kernel`. Also have you verified that the command is run only once in production crontab? Also check crontab for other users in case you mixed them during deployment `crontab -l` `crontab -l -u root`

Comment: ```crontab -l```  ```crontab -l -u root``` shows the same command like crontab -e

Comment: You either have place the `$schedule->call...` inside a php loop or you have defined `... artisan schedule:run ...` multiple times in one user's crontab or in crontab of multiple users. Is you system running in multiple servers like some kind of cluster?

Comment: No. Just a single server. I have ```$schedule->command``` as well every function or call inside my kernel runs multiple times.

Comment: multiple times in one user's crontab or in crontab of multiple users ? can you please explain how to check this? same like the command on top you put? I checked that shows same like ```crontab -e```

Comment: I'm interested to know what time-zone your server is running

Comment: My EC2 instance is in "UTC" and laravel in "Asia/Qatar"

Comment: I removed my command from ```crontab -e``` , but still the log is printing multiple times. what could be the reason?is it cached anywhere. i tried to remove cache as well no use

Comment: I found the issue. Long back i mistakenly put schedule:work instead of schedule:run. I replaced the command and restarted. But, those processes where still active. So i killed all the process related to old command and restarted. Now it is running only one time.Thank you everyone for your time.